# Sum of all products of k distinct integers in [1,n]

Tags: enumerative-combinatorics

Let $S=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ be the set of integers up to $n$ and $p_k(a_1,...,a_k)=a_1\cdots a_k$ the product of $k$ distinct integers $a_1,...,a_k \in S$. There are $\binom{n}{k}$ possibilities to construct such a product $p_k$. I was wondering if it is anyhow possible to estimate the sum of all such $k$-products $p_k$ or similarly the mean value as $n$ is large. Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Try induction over $n$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sum of all $k$-products of numbers in the interval $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, it is, the number you are referring to, is known as the Stirling number of the first kind: ${n+1 \brack {n+1-k}}$. There are plenty of articles that face the problem of giving estimations of these numbers out there.

Comment: Do you mean ${n+1 \brack {n-k+1}}$ ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is what I said above..

Comment: Hm, but $(x+1)\cdots(x+n)=\sum_{k=0}^n {n+1 \brack {k+1}} \, x^k$ and the coefficient of $x^k$ is the sum of all products of $n-k$ distinct integers in $\{1,...,n\}$. Therefore the coefficient of $x^{n-k}$ is the sum of all products of $k$ distinct integers which is ${n+1 \brack {n-k+1}}$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I edit and fix the typo now.